# Disable child's button from parent conditionally - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, lifecycle

I have a `Paginator` child component and I want to disable the left arrow button if it's on the first page and make it clickable again if I'm above the first page. The same thing with the right arrow button but with page number 5.

Here is the condition that I tried to write for this solution:

```
if (this.state.page <= 1) {
  this.setState({
    disabledPrev: true
  })
} else {
  this.setState({
    disabledPrev: false
  })
}

if (this.state.page >= 5) {
  this.setState({
    disabledNext: true
  })
} else {
  this.setState({
    disabledNext: false
  })
}
```

But it doesn't work, no matter where I put it. I think the problem is in the wrong usage of lifecycle methods.

Here is the whole code:

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import Loading from './components/Loading/Loading';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Table from './components/Table/Table';
import Paginator from './components/Paginator/Paginator';

const BASE_URL = 'https://api.udilia.com/coins/v1/'
export default class App extends React.Component{ 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('constructor');
    this.state = {
      currencies: null,
      isDataReady: false,
      page : 1,
      disabledPrev: false,
      disabledNext: false,
    }
  }

  fetchCurrencies = (pageNumber) => {
    fetch(`${BASE_URL}cryptocurrencies?page=${pageNumber}&perPage=20`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => json.currencies)
      .then(currencies => {
        this.setState({
          currencies: currencies,
          isDataReady: true,
        })
      });
  }

  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    console.log('will mount', this.state.page);

  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('didUpdate', this.state.page);

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('did mount', this.state.page);

    //Here is the conditions
    if (this.state.page <= 1) {
      this.setState({
        disabledPrev: true
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        disabledPrev: false
      })
    }

    if (this.state.page >= 5) {
      this.setState({
        disabledNext: true
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        disabledNext: false
      })
    }

    const {page} = this.state;

    this.fetchCurrencies(page);

  }

  //here is the event handler, I change the page value from here
  handlePaginationClick  = (direction) => () => {
    console.log('clicked', this.state.page);

    let page = direction === 'next' ? this.state.page + 1 : this.state.page - 1;

    this.setState({page})
    this.fetchCurrencies(page);
  }

  render(){
    console.log('render', this.state.page);

    return (
        !this.state.isDataReady
          ? <Loading />
          : <div className="App">
              <Header />
              <Table
                data={this.state.currencies}
              />
              <Paginator 
                prev={this.handlePaginationClick('prev')}
                next={this.handlePaginationClick('next')}
                page={this.state.page}
                disabledPrev={this.state.disabledPrev}
                disabledNext={this.state.disabledNext}
              />

            </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Paginator.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Paginator(props) {
    return(
        <div>
            <button disabled={props.disabledPrev} onClick={() => props.prev()}> &larr; </button>
            <span>page {props.page} of 10</span>
            <button disabled={props.disabledNext} onClick={() => props.next()}> &rarr; </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Change `prev={this.handlePaginationClick('prev')}` to `prev={() => this.handlePaginationClick('prev')}`, and similarly for `next`

Comment: Did you try to put those code inside `componentDidUpdate()` instead of `componentDidMount()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import Loading from './components/Loading/Loading';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Table from './components/Table/Table';
import Paginator from './components/Paginator/Paginator';

const BASE_URL = 'https://api.udilia.com/coins/v1/'
export default class App extends React.Component{ 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('constructor');
    this.state = {
      currencies: null,
      isDataReady: false,
      page : 1
    }
  }

  fetchCurrencies = (pageNumber) => {
    fetch(`${BASE_URL}cryptocurrencies?page=${pageNumber}&perPage=20`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => json.currencies)
      .then(currencies => {
        this.setState({
          currencies: currencies,
          isDataReady: true,
        })
      });
  }

  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    console.log('will mount', this.state.page);

  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('didUpdate', this.state.page);

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('did mount', this.state.page);
    const {page} = this.state;
    this.fetchCurrencies(page);

  }

  //here is the event handler, I change the page value from here
  handlePaginationClick  = (direction) => () => {
    console.log('clicked', this.state.page);

    let page = direction === 'next' ? this.state.page + 1 : this.state.page - 1;

    this.setState({page})
    this.fetchCurrencies(page);
  }

  render(){
    console.log('render', this.state.page);
    const {page} = this.state;
    const disabledPrev = page <=1 ? true : false;
    const disabledNext = page >=5 ? true : false;
    return (
        !this.state.isDataReady
          ? <Loading />
          : <div className="App">
              <Header />
              <Table
                data={this.state.currencies}
              />
              <Paginator 
                prev={this.handlePaginationClick('prev')}
                next={this.handlePaginationClick('next')}
                page={page}
                disabledPrev={disabledPrev}
                disabledNext={disabledNext}
              />

            </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need two state variables to handle the left and right arrow.
Modify the Paginator component to something like this:

```
import React from "react";

export default function Paginator({ page, min = 1, max = 5 }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button disabled={page <= min} onClick={() => props.prev()}>
        &larr;
      </button>
      <span>page {props.page} of 10</span>
      <button disabled={page >= max} onClick={() => props.next()}>
        &rarr;
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Pass `min` and `max` values to it.

```
<Paginator
  prev={this.handlePaginationClick("prev")}
  next={this.handlePaginationClick("next")}
  page={this.state.page}
  min={1}
  max={5}
/>
```

Comment: It works great, but it more comfortable for me to do all the logic in the parent component. Anyway it's a great solution and it works well and it deserves at least an upvote. Thank you))

Comment: @RobertHovhannisyan for handling login in the parent component you can try `disabledPrev={page<=1} disabledNext={page>=5}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <Paginator 
            prev={this.handlePaginationClick('prev')}
            next={this.handlePaginationClick('next')}
            page={this.state.page}
            disabledPrev={this.state.page <= 0}
            disabledNext={this.state.page >= 5}
          />
```

No need of below statements/Condition on componentDidmount:

```
if (this.state.page <= 1) {
  this.setState({
    disabledPrev: true
  })
} else {
  this.setState({
    disabledPrev: false
  })
}

if (this.state.page >= 5) {
  this.setState({
    disabledNext: true
  })
} else {
  this.setState({
    disabledNext: false
  })
}
```